# rails 4 before_actions with dynamic parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to set a before_action method with dynamic params, I keep getting an error **wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_categories
  before_action :redirect_if_path_has_changed, only: [:products, :detail]

  def home
  end

  def products
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @products = @category.products.order("created_at").page(params[:page]).per(6)

    redirect_if_path_has_changed(products_by_category_path(@category))
  end

  def detail
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    redirect_if_path_has_changed(product_details_path(@product))
  end

  private

  def set_categories
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def redirect_if_path_has_changed(path_requested)
    redirect_to path_requested, status: :moved_permanently if request.path != path_requested
  end
end
```

Thank you before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
before_action only: [:products, :detail] do
  redirect_if_path_has_changed("value")
end
```

Try this. The above works when you need to set any value or something before the action. In you case you want to first find the `product` or `detail` from database then you want to redirect to that path. So `before_action` just calls before the two actions which is not useful in your case.

Comment: Or is there any other way how to refactoring my code?

Comment: I don't understand that why are you calling it in `before_action` as you are again manually calling it in the `products` and `detail` action. I think the `before_action` is not necessary if you do this.

Comment: Im just practicing to DRY up my code, but I guess I now realize no need to do this. thank you sir :)

Comment: Yes. I have added some more details according to your case.